# Higher ramification groups of Artin-Schreier extensions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field

I am reading this paper http://www.numdam.org/article/JTNB_2005__17_2_689_0.pdf
I have been trying to prove Proposition 2.1(3) about stabilizing of higher ramification groups. Can anyone give me a hint to prove this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have an Artin-Schreier extension $L=K(b)$ where $b^p-b=a$
where $v(a)=-m$, $m>0$ and $p\nmid m$. Then $v_K(b)=-m/p$, or
$V_L(b)=-m$. The generator $\tau$ of the Galois group takes $b$ to $b+1$. To find the ramification groups under the
lower numbering you want to find the largest $n$ such that $\tau$
acts trivially on the ring $O_L/P_L^n$.

Let's identify a generator of $P_L$. There are integers $r$, $s$ with $1=-rm+sp$. Choose $r$ positive with $0<r<p$. We can take $\pi_L=b^r\pi_K^s$. Then
$$\frac{\tau(\pi_L)}{\pi_L}=\frac{(b+1)^r}{b^r}\equiv 1+r/b\pmod{b^{-2}}.$$
So
$$\tau(\pi_L)-\pi_L\equiv r \pi_L/b\pmod{\pi_L/b^2}.$$
So $\tau$ acts trivially on $O_L/P_L^n$ iff $n\le m$
(Serre, *Local Fields*, Lemma IV.1). This
determines the ramification jump for the lower numbering, and then
one can determine it for the upper numbering too.